# How to install .NET 4 during a ClickOnce installation

Tags: .net, installation, clickonce

Currently all users of my application have .NET 2.0 installed and launch it through ClickOnce. The way users launch this application is by clicking a link in some other page that references the .application file in IIS. Also some users have a shortcut in their desktops that points to the same link.

I recently upgraded my app to .NET 4 CP and I need to create a new deployment. The problem is most of the users do not have .NET 4 installed so in this new deployment I must make sure they will be prompted to install it.

If I simply deploy it and ask a user to open the new ClickOnce link, they are shown a message saying they need to have .NET 4 and then "contact your system administrator". I generated the bootstrapper but because the app is launched directly through the .application file I don't think it will ever work.

The only solution I have is to create another ClickOnce app that is developed in .NET 2.0 and works as a "launcher". This small app would check if .NET 4 is installed. If yes then launch the new app (another link) otherwise launches .NET 4 setup and ask the user to try again after reboot.

I'm looking to have a more easy process for the user, does anyone know? Creating a custom installer does not seem to solve my problem since it must run in .NET 4 which is not installed yet.

Comment: Be sure to target the 4.0 client profile, it is actively being pushed by ms update.

Comment: The problem is some users still have XP and this is a corporate network so not all MS updates get to be installed automatically.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone use the 4.0 Client Profile by choice?

Comment: @alex: Sorry if I was unclear. Targeting the client profile is not an alternative by itself. However it could significantly reduce the number of framework installs, depending on the target audience.

Comment: Aaah now i see you already target the client profile = CP.

Comment: @Ramhound why wouldn't you? Is there anything to support your 'claim'? I'm curious about your argument. I know reasons to support the use though, but not really in the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909885.aspx) expains how to detect the .net version from the useragent string. Depending on that, you can add the the link to your 4.0 clickonce app, or the bootstrapper. Then you can also explain in the page that the link wil launch an installer, and not the app.

No i never have done this myself, so no guarentees.....

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project properties and then select `publish tab` and under that click `PreRequisites` and then select .Net Framework 4.0 and then check `Download Prerequisites from the same location as my application.

Comment: That doesn't do it. As I explained, the application is launched by directly opening a link to the .application file. The bootstrapper is never called.